# Is there a way to block a specific email address on Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail

Is there a way to block a specific email address on Gmail, which would return a "address not found" server message to the sender (eventhough that email address exists on server)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a sense because then Google would be lying. Google does the right thing. It won't return a "address not found" server message to the sender (even though that email address exists on server).

You can create a filter that automatically deletes that person's email as it comes.

You might call that "blocking" which is basically you censoring that email address.